# Why is there usually a folder called 1033 in Microsoft Folders

Tags: windows

I found that most of the software by Microsoft contains a **1033** folder.
Is there any relation of the folder with Microsoft? Does it contain a special type of data?

Answer (score 30, accepted):

IIRC 1033 is some internal code for American English - so you will see directories with different numeric names in internationalised versions of the software.

**Edit:** I do RC - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0h88fahh lists 1033 as the "Locale ID" for US English.

Answer (score 9):

This is the folder that contains localization resources. 1033 is English, as windows is available in different languages. If you're intersted [here](http://www.science.co.il/Language/Locale-Codes.asp) is a page showing the language codes